# Autoit download whole source of site

Tags: php, download, autoit

I am trying to download source-code of website. I made it work in autoit as well as in php....buuut the problem is that the source code is not entire. A HTML of a few items generated by some script werent downloaded.

I am working on my school project about probability in casino games(especially roulette).And I want to download these numbers:
[NUMBERS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5j1gD.png)
 from page: http://csgocircle.com/ to create some statistics.
What do I do wrong ?

THANKS FOR YOUR HELP !

Autoit:

```
#include <Inet.au3>
#include <WinHttp.au3>

   $url="http://csgocircle.com/"
   $http_protocol = ObjCreate("winhttp.winhttprequest.5.1")
   $http_protocol.setrequestheader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
   $http_protocol.setrequestheader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.110 Safari/537.36")
   $http_protocol.open("GET", $url)
   $http_protocol.send($cookie)
   $http_protocol.waitforresponse
   $http_auth3 = $http_protocol.responsebody
   ConsoleWrite($http_auth3)

Exit
```

Or PHP:

```
<?php
$url="http://csgocircle.com/";
$homepage = file_get_contents($url);
echo htmlspecialchars( $homepage );
```

[image]

Comment: Problems when you're doing this is that you can't get JavaScript content since it's ran on the client side and you don't have any JavaScript interpreter built-in autoit or PHP. You'll need a better tool for the job (maybe phantomJS or similar would work).

Comment: Those numbers are not part of the source code, or even generated on the client-side.  Those numbers are generated on the server side, and pushed to the client.  So you will have to make a connection to the server to consume them, which will likely require authentication of some kind.  That said, it is likely that those numbers are generated according to well-known statistics, with likely a little manipulation (to account for physical characteristics of a roulette wheel).  You would probably save time implementing the number generator from scratch, to be fair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Autoit, you should load the URL in IE and get full html.

```
#include <IE.au3>

$url = "http://csgocircle.com/"
$oIE = _IECreate($url, 0, 0, 1, 0 )
;~ Sleep(2000) ; eventually do sleep in order to wait for JS/AJAX to finish the page
$html = _IEDocReadHTML($oIE)
_IEQuit($oIE)
ConsoleWrite($html)
```